# Update multiple columns with Different Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
               I have table following this format :

Id   BillNo:      Voucher No:
1   W2015-16/0001  W2015-16/0001
2   W2015-16/0002  W2015-16/0002
3   W2015-16/0003  W2015-16/0003
4   W2015-16/0004  W2015-16/0004
5   W2015-16/0005  W2015-16/0005
6   W2015-16/0006  W2015-16/0006
7   W2015-16/0007  W2015-16/0007
8   W2015-16/0008  W2015-16/0008
9   W2015-16/0009 W2015-16/0009
10   W2015-16/0010  W2015-16/0010
```

But Instead of this Format:
Now I want to Update All "Voucher No" and "Bill No" below on this format :

```
Id   BillNo:      Voucher No:
1   W0001/2015-16 W0001/2015-16
2   W0002/2015-16 W0002/2015-16
3   W0003/2015-16 W0003/2015-16
4   W0004/2015-16 W0004/2015-16
5   W0005/2015-16 W0005/2015-16
6   W0006/2015-16 W0006/2015-16
7   W0007/2015-16 W0007/2015-16
8   W0008/2015-16 W0008/2015-16
9   W0009/2015-16 W0009/2015-16
10  W0010/2015-16 W0010/2015-16
11  W0011/2015-16 W0011/2015-16
```

like this i have a 1000+ records i should update , But i don't know is this possible  to do in Lesser time, Kindly give your suggestion , i am new to SQL
Thanks Advance

Comment: please don't tag irrelevant products. how is mysql and oracle used here?

Comment: Question -> Only First CHAR is always a constant value or can expect more values in first place? W2015 .. can it be WER2015?

Comment: only first char is constant , cannot modified @user2066540

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET BillNo = SUBSTRING(BillNo,1,1) + SUBSTRING(BillNo,10,4) + '/' + SUBSTRING(BillNo,2,7)
, VoucherNo = SUBSTRING(VoucherNo,1,1) + SUBSTRING(VoucherNo,10,4) + '/' + SUBSTRING(VoucherNo,2,7)
```

Test:

```
DECLARE @a NVARCHAR(max) = 'W2015-16/0001' 
SELECT SUBSTRING(@a,1,1) +
SUBSTRING(@a,10,4) + '/' + SUBSTRING(@a,2,7)
```

Comment: It's Awesome ,, Really very thank full, Giving Ur Code is Working Fine and greatful  @Nenad Zivkovic

Comment: Thanks for All  helping  my problem ;)

Comment: @FelishAnand Sure, no problem: Substring function splits your string into parts.  SUBSTRING(BillNo,1,1) takes 1 character from position 1, which is `W` in your example. SUBSTRING(BillNo,2,7) is 7 characters starting from position 2 = `2015-16`, and SUBSTRING(BillNo,10,4) is 4 characters from 10th position which is `0001`... So basically you split your input string into parts and reassemble it in different order.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everything is in a fixed format, then you would just use `update` and string manipulations:

```
update table t
    set billno = left(billno, 1) + right(billno, 4) + '/' + substring(billno, 2, 7),
        VoucherNo = left(VoucherNo, 1) + right(VoucherNo, 4) + '/' + substring(VoucherNo, 2, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way to achieve this. You may need to define some patterns in SQL to replace and play with all string functions. Here is

```html
declare @name varchar(50) ='W2015-16/0001';
select SUBSTRING(STUFF(@name,2,0,(SUBSTRING(@name,CHARINDEX('/',@name) + 1,len(@name)) + '/')),0,14)
--W0001/2015-16
```

This gives you the result that you are looking for. So you need to set this into your update statement by joining with the table by ID. This would work only if the pattern you have given is correct.